# File get content or cURL getting 404 page instead of main string

Tags: php, curl, domdocument, file-get-contents

I was trying to get string from website but i am getting 404 page of external website instead of index page string.

I have tried with both `cURL` and `file_get_contents`. Both returning 404 from external website instead of returning the string of index page.

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://www.creditkarma.ca");
echo $homepage;
```

cURL :

```
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);    

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
$homepage = file_get_contents_curl("https://www.creditkarma.ca");
echo $homepage;
```

The code should return the string of index page but it return the 404 page from external website. How can i solve this. i need a string of index page.

Note : it returning 404 of external website not from my `.htaccess`

Comment: I would guess they have bloked your IP, it works for me, but if I keep hitting them I expect I would also get noticed and blocked as well

Comment: cURL could be more reliable, as you can make the request look like its coming from a browser and not from a program. If you show the cURL code you tried, maybe we could suggest a few improvements

Comment: @RiggsFolly other page of external website working fine. i am able to get a string of all other web page of external website except index page. if they blocked my `IP`. all the pages should get blocked not just index

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have updated `cURL` code in question.

Comment: Ok, yes, but there are ways of blocking you than the simple one I suggested

Comment: Yea, no `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` so you dont look like a browser. Maybe they only block `index.php`

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have added useragent from `zak` suggestion but still same error. i have updated my question with new code.

Comment: Well if you are blocked you are blocked. So try from another IP Address for a start

Comment: The block may timeout, but that could take ??? Who knows how long

Comment: @RiggsFolly you mean my `internet IP` or `web server Public IP`? because i tested with VPN changing IP but same result. are you getting string of home page? or your also getting `404` page of external website.

Comment: It will probably be your server that is blocked as this is PHP it will not be being run as your PC but as the server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241013/discussion-between-poonam-and-riggsfolly).

Comment: @RiggsFolly i got it. But i use `cloudflare` and it `A record` is dynamic. So no way they can find my real `IP` and ban it.

Comment: Well 2 other people, @Zak and I can run both of these mechanisms and get output. So somehow the target site has managed to identify you and say No more stealing our content, unless we say you can. So contact then and ask for access

Comment: @Poonam if you read my update, and comment .. You are being blocked EITHER by networking or ANOTHER filter --  Try what we suggested.  Move IP, and/or machine, and troubleshoot where you got blocked ..  AND furthermore .. If this is a legitimate project, contact the site owner and ask to be whitelisted

Comment: @Zak Ok. got it. Thanks zak. i will test with new server and will update you.

Comment: @RiggsFolly i am going to test in different server. Will update you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a CURL statement, if you want to retrieve the HTML of a page, you should be using `headers`.  As a security precaution, a lot of websites will deny traffic (or result in 404) if browser information is not apparent. So when I do this .. I try to "emulate" my statement, as if it were a browser. Something like this should fit the bill -- As noted in your updated code above, you are not denoting an "agent":

```
$url="https://www.creditkarma.ca";
$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

**UPDATE**

I have tested this as a "stand alone" php script .. And get the following results:

```
*   Trying 104.100.143.79:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to www.creditkarma.ca (104.100.143.79) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
* Server certificate:
*  subject: businessCategory=Private Organization; jurisdictionC=US; jurisdictionST=Delaware; serialNumber=4313894; C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=Credit Karma Inc.; CN=www.creditkarma.ca
*  start date: Mar 16 00:00:00 2020 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 21 12:00:00 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "www.creditkarma.ca" matched cert's "www.creditkarma.ca"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.creditkarma.ca
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Accept: */*

* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< x-content-security-policy:
< Server: CK-FG-server
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< ORIGIN-ENV: production
< ORIGIN-DC: us-east4
< Expires: Wed, 12 Jan 2022 18:20:46 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store
< Pragma: no-cache
< Date: Wed, 12 Jan 2022 18:20:46 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Connection: Transfer-Encoding
< Set-Cookie: ck_cabf=IjA5MTRmMDQ2LTE3OTAtNDQ5MC1hODA3LWUzZTRlZDcwYTdlYSI=; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Thu, 12 Jan 2023 18:20:46 GMT; Secure; SameSite=Strict; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: ck_crumb=6da1442eb87cee1a6c0c08c56a9b07826949e3dc130925b0fcb774a83d566b71f5a9b634c4e4f198ae8dc4a6722abf41; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: ck_trace_id=5544f4ea-9d03-462b-ab5f-8a81c70c6c81; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; Path=/
< Set-Cookie: ck_lang=en; SameSite=Strict; Path=/
<
* Connection #0 to host www.creditkarma.ca left intact
string(63139) "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
 ..... Rest of page here
```

Comment: I have added agent but still no success.

Comment: I have updated my question with code modified from your success. can you check that and let me know what wrong

Comment: Yea, I get an answer using file_get_content() and this cURL. Poonam you are blocked, try from another PC probably another PC not behind the same router

Comment: See my update .. If you are not getting the same result with a stand alone script .. You are specifically being blocked via other networking rules and/or custom filters on the server side.  I would suggest testing from a different IP and machine.  This can happen if the host "thinks" you are trying to scrape, or DOS attack

Comment: @Zak Ok, i am trying with other server. I have updated my code based on your suggestion. can you check if my code is correct in question.

Comment: Yes the code in your question works .. Minus the missing `}` after the return

Comment: yes that a typo error. i am checking on different server. i will update you my result :) thanks mate